# Proving a claim about sub-sets using a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove the following, using graph theory:

Let $S=\{1,2,...,n\}$, and $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ **different** sub-sets of $S$ (but they don't have to be disjoint). Prove that there exists $x\in S$ such that the sets: $A_1\cup \{x\}, A_2\cup \{x\},...,A_n\cup \{x\}$ are different from each other.

**Hint**: Build a graph so that its vertices are $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$.

I tried using the hint, and I understood that somehow I need to define the edges between the vertices (for example, two vertices will be connected by an edge if and only if the two subsets are equal or maybe if they have only one different element between them, etc.), but I can't seem to gain any ground.. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general idea of how I think this problem can be solved.

Build a digraph so that the vertices are $A_1,A_2....,A_n$ such that the edge from any vertex $A_i$ to $A_j$ means "$A_i$ is included in $A_j$"

Proof that it's impossible to have a loop of any size, because that would mean: "$A_i$ is included in $A_j$ and $A_j$ is included in $A_w$ and $A_w$ ...  and $A_e$ is included in $A_i$" which is absurd, because it means $A_i$ is equal to $A_j$ and $A_w$ and $A_e$.

Then the graph has to have an element $A_x$ which it's out-degree is $0$.

Let $x \in A_x$ and $\forall i \in \{ 1,2,...,x-1,x+1,...n \}, x \notin A_i$ and make the graph such $A_1\cup \{x\}, A_2\cup \{x\},...,A_n\cup \{x\}$.

Look at that graph and proof there are no loops, and you should be there.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will try it out now and see where it gets me.

Comment: I don't see why this has to happen:
Let $x \in A_x$ and $\forall i \in \{ 1,2,...,x-1,x+1,...n \}, x \notin A_i$. How do we know that there's such an $x$? We know that $A_x$ has an out-degree of $0$, so it isn't a subset of any of the others, but that doesn't mean that it has a member that isn't included in any of the others.

Comment: Yes, you are right, let me think a little more about this